# count number of occurrences in list python

Tags: python

I have a set that contains all the possible values present in a list. What I want is to know how much of each value are present in the list.

So, I have:

```
set_a = ("a","b", "c", "d")
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "c"]
```

What I want is this:

```
a 1
b 1
c 2
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I may have been a bit to quick to ask (just a bit under stress :-P) but I tried this `for i in set_a: print i, lst.len(i)`

Comment: thanks for pointing to the other question. How do I iterate over a set?

Comment: The normal way: `for i in your_set: ...`

Comment: right.. thanks.. this is a good example of: " I have no patience to figure it out myself right now.." thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You will see solutions here: [How can I count the occurrences of a list item in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

For instance you can do:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1].count(1)
```

Comment: If you find a duplicate, please comment on or flag the question.